# bootstrap:themed wrong constant NameError -> const_defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to run the following using Rails 3.2.2, switched to 3.2.1 and tried another machine to see if it was more core / OS related.

I try:

```
rails g bootstrap:themed events
```

I get:

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `const_defined?': wrong constant name event (NameError)
    from /Users/charleyhine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `block in constantize'
    from /Users/charleyhine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `each'
    from /Users/charleyhine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `constantize'
    from /Users/charleyhine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:54:in `constantize'
    from /Users/charleyhine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.0.4/lib/generators/bootstrap/themed/themed_generator.rb:58:in `columns'
    from (erb):6:in `template'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to downgrade the gem version. Instead, just change:

```
rails g bootstrap:themed events
```

to:

```
rails g bootstrap:themed Events
```

You need to capitalize and pluralize the model name, which is dumb, but it works

Comment: I don't have a model. I am just using the controller. How do I get along with that?

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same error. After searching for similar errors - I figured it must be a problem with the latest version of bootstrap, as I was not getting this error earlier.

I got the error with the version 2.0.4. The following line in the Gemfile followed by "bundle install" solved it for me.

gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', '2.0.2'